# Webhook response: Show suggestion chips with followupEventInput

Tags: dialogflow-es

The google assistant does not show the suggestion chips sent into the webhook response.

```
{
"fulfillmentText": "Some text",
"payload": {
    "google": {
        "expectUserResponse": true,
        "richResponse": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "simpleResponse": {
                        "textToSpeech": "What number ?"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "suggestions": [
                {
                    "title": "One"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Two"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
"followupEventInput": {
    "name": "numbers",
    "parameters": {
        "param1": "this is it"
    }
}}
```

The interesting thing is that if I remove the "followupEventInput" field, the suggestion chips are displayed.

Can someone give me a hint on this behaviour ?

Comment: can you be more clear, what you are looking for?

Comment: Sure:
I have the "numbers" intent which I want to be fired next(followupEventInput). I want that intent besides its response to also show the suggestion chips sent in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you're sending back doesn't do what you likely want it to do.

The `followupEventInput` means that the Intent is triggered *immediately*, rather than sending back the rest of the reply (including the suggestions). Instead, the reply from the followup event is sent back.

It sounds like you want to send back a reply and then, no matter what the user says or selects, their message is sent to a specific action. Keep in mind that Dialogflow Intents are triggered based on the user's actions and shaped based on the contexts that might be set.

In this case, it sounds like you may want to set an `outputContext` to influence which Intents will be examined when collecting the user's response. You can then have an Intent that takes this as an input Context and matches the possible phrases. If you truly want to get whatever the user says in the reply, you can use a Fallback Intent with the input Context set appropriately.

While you *can* redirect to another Intent to send output, usually this is unnecessary. Remember that Intents best represent the user's *input* rather than your agent's *output*. Particularly if you're using your webhook to generate and send a reply - just send the reply.

Comment: Hi Prisoner,

Yes, I a using context. The user responded, an intent caught his answer and sent it to my back-end. I processed the response and then I want to trigger the next intent which will ask a question. What I want is to help the user answer to that question with the suggestion chips sent dynamically from my back-end.

Isn't this the way I should do that ?

Comment: Why are you triggering the "next intent" to ask the question instead of just asking the question?

Comment: Hmm...  that is a good question. I could just ask the question -> set an outputContext to be sure a certain intent will catch the response and that's it huh ?

Comment: Exactly. {: I've elaborated my answer to basically say this.

Comment: If the answer works for you, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.

Comment: To add, I think that it's important for applications to be easy to use. By showing a user suggestion chips in order to make answering a question easier is important. By minimizing user input typed input, and replacing with suggestion chips, you funnel your response to your desired outcome. @Prisoner Does this make sense?

Comment: @Jches - yes and no. Yes, suggestion chips are important to help guide a user. The OP isn't clear, but they *wanted* suggestion chips in conjunction with using a redirect, which is neither possible nor necessary. However... you can't assume that a user will take the suggestions, or even be using a device that displays them, so you can't really "funnel" the conversation. Doing so would create a poor VUI.